# Javascript code to call database

Tags: javascript, php, database, session, post

/* below is the javascript code to display countdown for my expired membership. What i want to do is that to change that bold date and time to a data from my database.
    *database=thesis
    *table=user_accounts
    *attribute=start_time/*

```
<script>
   CountDownTimer(**'01/22/2014 10:1 AM**', 'countdown');
    function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
    {

        var end = new Date(dt);

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I DON'T KNOW HOW TO CALL MY DATABASE DATA USING JAVASCRIPT!

Comment: And what have you tried? Where did you fail at? what do you need help with? we're not going to write your call to the database for you.

Comment: BOLD does not work in CODE blocks

Comment: Use PHP to output the variables to the page. Use those variables.

Comment: I didn't tried any javascript code to call my database data!.. that's why I asked this question because I don't know how to code javascript. All i want to ask is that. HOW to get my attribute from the database where it was stored using javascript code so that I can change that date and time there depending on the date and time when it was started.

Comment: And yeah..!! i dont know also how to put php code inside javascript code!please please

Comment: okay!!>. I am trying..!! thank you!...for the help...

Answer (score 1):

You don't use client-side JS to read database data (it's plausible, depending on the DB and how it's set up, but it's also a very big security hole to let anybody in the world edit your database).

You use a server-side language to handle requests from JS (through XMLHttpRequest -- "AJAX"), then from the server, once you figure out what the JS wants, connect to your DB, get the data, and return it to the front-end script.

Comment: last question could you explode this one 2014-01-22 and then change the "-" to "/".. please..

Comment: lsst favor... if you could just give me the could... please....!!including the date..!! i really don't know how to that..!! i mean seriously ... please..